# Image is coming as rotated when rendered from base 64 in HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova, html5-canvas

I am taking a photo from iOS camera which is giving me base64 data. I am trying to render that in canvas but canvas is rendering image as rotated.

But if i render same image in img tag it is coming in correct orientation.

This is working fine in android canvas. Issue is happening just for iOS canvas. Either i take a photo or select from library, This issue happens.

Below is the code to take Photo

```
const options: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 50,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.PNG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
  sourceType: isCamera ? this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA :
    this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
}



this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
  let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
  this.info.photo.value = base64Image;
}, (err) => {
  // Handle error
});
```

Below is code to draw in canvas

```
  img = new Image();
  img.src = this.info.photo.value;
  img.onload = function () {
    const height = img.naturalHeight;
    const width = img.naturalWidth;
    const imgWidth = width / height * 200;
    ctx.drawImage(img, (ctx.canvas.width - imgWidth) / 2, font + 20 * pixelRatio, imgWidth, 200);
  }
```

Comment: Sounds like it could be an issue relating to exif data on the image (jpeg right?). The exif data will say the image is rotated even though the raw image data is not so it will appear "rotated" incorrectly on canvas. Not sure how to fix but thought I would share what I know to give you a lead.

Comment: Thanks for your thought. Will it be only for canvas? FYI, I can see image properly in img tag. Also it works fine in android canvas. Only issue is with iOS canvas

Answer (score 0):

I corrected it by giving correctOrientation option to true in CameraOptions

```
const options: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 50,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.PNG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
  sourceType: isCamera ? this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA : this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
  correctOrientation: true,
}
```